# OpenShift Origin - Add node from web console

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-web-console

Is possible to add/manage `node` to cluster from web console as in Apache Rancher? What is the best way to do it from `cli`?

Thanks

Comment: For normal web console of OpenShift no. If using Red Hat OpenShift Container Platform (OCP) rather than Origin, I believe you could do it from CloudForms if that was being used.

Comment: I think it's very restrictive, k8s dashboard show cluster's node status and allocation, apache rancher has the functionalty to add node from web console, any way open shift currently does not support Ubuntu / Debian OS, so i 'm asking what is its strength

Comment: The OpenShift web console was mainly intended for developers, it is not a pure operations web interface. In future OpenShift version there will be an option to also access an operations web interface based on what has come from CoreOS Tectonic. I don't know if that will include an ability to add nodes though.

Comment: What the OS for the underlying nodes is doesn't really matter. Even if using CentOS/Fedora/RHEL for the nodes, you can still deploy images which use Ubuntu, Debian or Alpine.

Comment: As to how to add nodes, there are currently Ansible playbooks for performing various admin operations which affect the cluster. Adding an additional node isn't necessarily trivial and why ultimately it falls back to Ansible playbooks to run the steps, even if one of the web interfaces provides an option to trigger it.

Comment: With open shift ansible in rhel works ok, i know the container Os can be evry thing (linux based) but the host os has to be RedHat